# Custom window in java

Tags: java, user-interface

How would I make a window that isn't native to java like in LWJGL where you can set the display to its own window and it isn't using java's libraries. I don't want responses about reinventing the wheel, because I'm just doing this for fun, I just want to know if it's possible and if it is, where to start

Comment: Do some research into JNI/JNA

Answer (score 0):

You can use java native interface (JNI) you can see a hello world sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378826/How-to-wrap-a-Csharp-library-for-use-in-Java).

and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35908/Hosting-WPF-Content-in-a-Java-Application) is the link to a more complicated project with WPF clock component in java frame, that I learned a lot from back in the days when I need to learn about JNI.